# Running Hadoop mapreduce Django apps on a Heroku dynamo

Tags: python, django, hadoop, heroku

Is it readily possible to integrate a Hadoop client with python (django) mapreduce apps/scripts *remotely* (on Heroku dynamos or [from a free cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078504/free-hadoop-cluster-for-experiments)) as is done *locally* in these examples:

- http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/
- http://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/11/17/python-map-reduce-on-hadoop---a-beginners-tutorial.html
- [Hadoop and Django, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667868/hadoop-and-django-is-it-possible)

This Heroku addon led me to believe this might be possible: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/treasure-data. But this app isn't free and the learning-curve-to-cost ratio is not an obvious investment to me.

My motivation to cross the Heroku/Django/Hadoop bridge is to upgrade my current Django apps with social media mining features.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you can install Hadoop on heroku, but even if you can what's the point?

Hadoop makes distributed computing easy, if you are going to run it in the Heroku free tier you will have a cluter of one, maybe two dynos. To harness the power of Hadoop you need more hardware. Also heroku dynos have 512 Mb of RAM....

Comment: Thanks, you're right and I'm updating my question in response to emphasize my aim.

Comment: BTW, if you want to do it just for fun I think It could be a very interesting experiment :) Hadoop is not trivial to install  and I would love to know if it could be installed in heroku